# "Error: \caption outside float" em R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, markdown

Quando tento compilar o meu código R Markdown, recebo o seguinte erro:

> ! Package caption Error: \caption outside float.
>
> See the caption package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.
>   ...
>   l.336 \caption
>
> pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF Erro: pandoc document conversion
>   failed with error 43 Além disso: Warning message: execução do comando
>   '"C:/Users/araujoic/AppData/Local/Pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS
>   rmarkdown.utf8.md --to latex --from
>   markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash
>   --output rmarkdown.pdf --template "C:\Users\araujoic\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex"
>   --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --include-in-header
>   "C:\Users\araujoic\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQXmi4e\file21b83d93844"'
>   teve status 43  Execução interrompida

Como posso resolvê-lo?

Comment: Seria interessante por o trecho onde isso ocorre. Aproveite e dê uma olhada nesse tópico: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111791/caption-outside-float-error

Answer (score 2):

Você precisar usar um `\caption{}` dentro de um ambiente de tabelas `(\being{table} ... \end{table}` ou de figuras `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}`.

Caso contrário, você terá problema na compilação.